# Is there a way to convert a react-native app from npx to Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Having successfully ejected a react-native app first created using 'expo init' with the 'expo eject' command, I was wondering if there is a way to go the other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. You cannot go back to expo again after you have ejected from expo to a bare react-native app becuase now your code is splitted into two halves, one in `android` directory and `ios` directory.

There's no going back around, but you can use the expo libraries which you were using in expo , by simply installing [rn-unimodules](https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules) in your react native project.

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to migrate an existing `@react-native-community/cli`  based project to `expo-cli`. In fact, they can both be used [simultaneously](https://docs.expo.dev/faq/#should-i-use-expo-cli-or-react-native-cli). You can pick and choose which Expo features you'd like to use. That said, chances are you'll run into fewer issues if you adopt Expo fully.

Expo also supports custom native modules, which they call [plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/introduction/).

Since Expo has some premium features, it is in their interest to make it as easy as possible for previously ejected apps to start using more of their free tools so that they'll be more inclined to start using their premium features.